# Cloning github repo meteorite exception

Tags: github, meteor, meteorite, ubuntu-12.10

Right after installing meteorite from npm

```
npm install -g meteorite
```

I tried to add the router package

```
mrt add router --verbose
```

So that's what i'm getting

```
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
Resolving dependency tree
Connecting to atmosphere.meteor.com:443...
Connected..
Getting package info for router...
Got package info for router.
Getting package info for page-js-ie-support...
Got package info for page-js-ie-support.
Getting package info for HTML5-History-API...
Got package info for HTML5-History-API.
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
Resolving dependency tree
Getting package info for router...
Got package info for router.
Getting package info for page-js-ie-support...
Got package info for page-js-ie-support.
Getting package info for HTML5-History-API...
Got package info for HTML5-History-API.
✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.5.4.1

/usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:114
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
                                                              ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git
Please check https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting for potential explanations.
```

It is connected to port 443, but It can not clone the repo..

So I was looking into Atmosphere files and I found the exception here:

https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/lib/sources/git.js#L103-L114

But how can I fix this ?

PS: I only have the problem on my Ubuntu 12.10 and not in my Debian 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was somewhere in the ubuntu "Git" package.

I removed and reinstalled it and the cloning worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

1) Try again in a few minutes / few hours. Such errors sometimes happen randomly and disappear after some time.

2) Try `iron-router` instead. It's way better.

Comment: I've been trying since yesterday.. Iron-router gives the same problem